# SilverStripe random order for ArrayList()

Tags: php, arraylist, silverstripe

I know that we can randomly sort a `DataList` with the following:

```
$example = Example::get()->sort('RAND()');
```

But when I try to randomly sort an `ArrayList` it doesn't work. I can sort an `ArrayList` by `ID DESC`, but not with `RAND()`.

Is there a way to make an `ArrayList` randomly sort its items?

Example:

```
public function AllTheKits() {
    $kits = Versioned::get_by_stage('KitsPage', 'Live');
    $kitsArrayList = ArrayList::create();

    foreach ($kits as $kit) {
        if ($kit->MemberID == Member::currentUserID()) {
            $kitsArrayList->push($kit);
        }
    }
    return $kitsArrayList;      
}
```

In a page:

```
public function getKitsRandom() {
    return $this->AllTheKits()->sort('RAND()');
}
```

This does not work in a template with `<% loop KitsRandom %>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. This is the best workaround I can come up with:

```
foreach($myArrayList as $item) {
    $item->__Sort = mt_rand();
}

$myArrayList = $myArrayList->sort('__Sort');
```

Comment: It's not like I expected but it's efficient enough to not make duplicated codes. I will try this soon. Thanks!

Comment: I tested this in morning... That works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could randomly sort the `DataList` before you loop over it, instead of trying to randomly sort the `ArrayList`:

```
public function AllTheKits($sort = '') {
    $kits = Versioned::get_by_stage('KitsPage', 'Live', '', $sort);
    $kitsArrayList = ArrayList::create();

    foreach ($kits as $kit) {
        if ($kit->MemberID == Member::currentUserID()) {
            $kitsArrayList->push($kit);
        }
    }
    return $kitsArrayList;      
}

public function getKitsRandom() {
    return $this->AllTheKits('RAND()'));
}
```

As a side note, you can filter the original DataList to fetch `KitsPages` that relate to this `MemberID` in the `Versioned::get_by_stage` call:

```
public function AllTheKits($sort = '') {
    $kits = Versioned::get_by_stage(
        'KitsPage',
        'Live',
        'MemberID = ' . Member::currentUserID(),
        $sort
    );
    $kitsArrayList = ArrayList::create($kits);

    return $kitsArrayList;      
}
```

You could also just do this:

`return KitsPage::get()->filter('MemberID', Member::currentUserID())->sort('RAND()');`

When you are viewing the live site this will only get the live `KitPages`.

Comment: That last approach with `filter` is definitely the cleanest and also most efficient approach.